# Animating constraints changes with setNeedsLayout

Tags: ios, animation, autolayout, uikit

The standard way of animating constraint changes is.

```
// Change constraints like:
someConstraint.constant = 100 

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
    view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

However I was watching the [WWDC 2015 session on multitasking on iPad and at the end](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/205/?time=3223) it said don't use `layoutIfNeeded` in animation blocks, use `setNeedsLayout` instead. However I've always thought that this would mean the layout happens later in the run loop and so outside of the animation block. Perhaps it remembers it was called in an animation block?

I tried replacing `layoutIfNeeded` with `setNeedsLayout` in my code, and it seemed to work. Is this just coincidence and we actually should be animating autolayout changes with `setNeedsLayout`?

[image: Slide from WWDC video showing to use setNeedsLayout instead]

Comment: Those specific comments are (or, I should say, appear to be) related strictly to animations during size changes. If you're changing the constraint as a result of a button tap (for example), are you sure you're not seeing a difference? Change your duration to `2.0` and see if it really does animate over 2-seconds, e.g. a nice, slow "slide" to the new position.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for `layoutIfNeeded()` states:

> Use this method to force the view to update its layout immediately. When using Auto Layout, the layout engine updates the position of views as needed to satisfy changes in constraints. Using the view that receives the message as the root view, this method lays out the view subtree starting at the root. If no layout updates are pending, this method exits without modifying the layout or calling any layout-related callbacks.

The documentation for `setNeedsLayout()` states:

> Call this method on your application’s main thread when you want to adjust the layout of a view’s subviews. This method makes a note of the request and returns immediately. Because this method does not force an immediate update, but instead waits for the next update cycle, you can use it to invalidate the layout of multiple views before any of those views are updated. This behavior allows you to consolidate all of your layout updates to one update cycle, which is usually better for performance.

`setNeedsLayout()` defers the layout for all subviews of the view, till the next cycle of the runloop, thereby consolidating all the changes to the appropriate time, instead of side-stepping the process and forcing the layout to occur instantaneously. Yes you should use `setNeedsLayout()` instead of `layoutIfNeeded()` in the UIView.animate function. Be a good citizen if possible.

Comment: This doesn’t say anything about animation though